# How to dynamically create a Java class List?

Tags: java, groovy

I am using groovy 1.8 where i want to have a list something like this 
`List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new List<MyQueryClass>()` 
So that using the below loop i can add more to this list, how can I do that?

```
def queryxml=new XmlSlurper().parse(QueryProvider.class.getResourceAsStream( '/queries.xml' ))
    queryxml.query.each { node ->
        operation="${node.@operation.text()}"
        if(operation.equals(op.create.toString()))
        {
            query="${node.text()}"
            println "$query"
            MyQueryClass myQuery=new MyQueryClass (query)
            queryl.add(myQuery)
        }           
    }
```

Comment: where did you define queryl? this seems that it should be working if you define queryl above queryxml... what error do you get?

Comment: I define `queryl` above this code, when i write `List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new List<MyQueryClass>()` i get `Groovy:You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'java.util.List'` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give us much to go on, but assuming you have a class:

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical class MyQuery {
  String queryText
}
```

And your XML is similar to:

```
def xml = '''<xml>
  <query operation="create">
    This is q1
  </query>
  <query operation="q2">
    This is q2
  </query>
  <query operation="create">
    This is q3
  </query>
</xml>'''
```

Then you should be able to use `findAll` to limit the xml to just the nodes of interest, followed by `collect` to build up your list of objects like so:

```
def queryxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

List<MyQuery> query = queryxml.query.findAll { node ->  // Filter the nodes
  node.@operation.text() == 'create'
}.collect { node ->                                     // For each matching node, create a class
  new MyQuery( node.text().trim() )
}

println query
```

And that prints out:

```
[MyQuery(This is q1), MyQuery(This is q3)]
```

PS: The `groovy.transform.Canonical` annotation [is explained here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html)

Comment: I think somewhere I was not able to question properly, B4 I was doing something like `List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new List<MyQueryClass>[5]` and once i added I got `6` as its size, but actually only 1 query was getting added, so my question was how to do it dynamically, I figured it out, as I cannot create an instance out of a abstract interface `java.util.List` So finally i did `List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new ArrayList<MyQueryClass>()` to make it work :) Thanks though for answering, I'll give you an up for giving an answer

Comment: @Abhishek As you're using groovy, you shouldn't need to do `new ArrayList<MyQueryClass>()` at all...

Comment: what should I be using instead, because if i use `List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new List<MyQueryClass>()` i get an error mark where it says `Groovy:You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'java.util.List'`

Comment: @Abhishek Have you looked at the code I posted?  That generates a list from the `collect` call.  Or, you could just do: `List<MyQueryClass> queryl = []` which does the same as your line of code.

Answer (score 3):

My apologies, I could not convey my question properly. 
I figured it out, as I cannot create an instance out of a abstract interface java.util.List

```
List<MyQueryClass> queryl=new ArrayList<MyQueryClass>()
```

does the work. Thanks tim and draganstankovic